# Segmentation Fault 11, bad variable?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

When I compile a source file I receive a segmentation fault: 11 error. I have been able to narrow it down, and I know that the error is coming from this function:

```
struct drecord { /* use this struct for double-linked lists */
int value;
struct drecord *previous;
struct drecord *next;
};

void sort()
{

struct drecord *currentNode;
struct drecord *end;
for(end=head->previous; end!=NULL && end!=head; end=end->previous)
{
    for(currentNode = head; currentNode != NULL && currentNode != end; currentNode = currentNode->next)
    {


        if (currentNode->value > currentNode->next->value)
        {
            swap(currentNode, currentNode->next);
        }

        currentNode = currentNode->next;
    }
}
printf("\n");

printf("%d", numElements);
while(numElements > 0)
{
    currentNode = head;
    printf("Sorted elements: %d", currentNode->value);
    delete(currentNode->value);
    numElements = numElements - 1;
}

}

void swap(struct drecord *drecord1, struct drecord *drecord2)
{
int aux = drecord1->value;
drecord1->value = drecord2->value;
drecord2->value = aux;
}
```

Even more specifically, I think that it is coming from the part of the code after printf("\n"), because printf("\n") works but nothing past it does. I had thought that it was a problem with the variable numElements, but I have this same exact code in another source file and it works perfectly. numElements is a global variable. What is wrong?

Comment: Use the debugger to identify exactly which line is causing the seg-fault, then work backwards.

Comment: Time to run  your code under a debugger. Get will tell you exactly where the problematic instruction is.

Comment: If currentNode->next is NULL or end, then what will currentNode->next->value be?

Comment: I'm having trouble using the debugger. This function correctly sorts the linked list. The problem is when I am trying to print out the linked list; that is when the segmentation fault occurs.

Comment: 1) `swap()` is suspicious.  Expect something like `swap(&currentNode, &currentNode->next);`  Would be nice to show `swap()`.  2) swapping without potentially affecting `head` is likely wrong.  3) Show `struct drecord` definition.

Comment: I added in that code. I now realize that the problem is not numElements. So it's either currentNode or head.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code, but let's focus on the one likely to cause the crash you're seeing:

You call `delete(currentNode->value);` but isn't `value` an int? At least, that's how you treat it in your implementation of `swap`. If it is an `int`, then what *exactly* are you deleting?

Perhaps your intent was to delete `currentNode`, instead. But even that is wrong: please note that that while that will successfully delete `currentNode` (assuming that it was allocated with `new` of course), it won't change the head pointer. It will continue to point to where it pointed before: the memory you just called delete on.

So, either way, you're screwed and you should rethink what you're doing in that loop.

---

As a postscript: while this kind of bug is trivial to find even without a debugger by casual inspection of the code, *please* invest the time to learn how to use a debugger. It's a critical skill for *anyone* who wants to program and it will pay dividends: not only will it help you track bugs down, but it will give you a deeper understanding of what is happening and make you a better programmer in the process.